# Hola tengo una duda respecto a porque es posible a este código usando la interfaz ActionListener

Tags: java

mi dudad es respecto a este código:

```
ActionListener fontas = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
        };
```

por lo que entiendo se trata de una clase interna anónima, por ese aspecto no tengo problemas, lo que me genera confusión es porque es posible instanciar la interfaz ActionListener como se muestra en el código anterior, hasta donde tengo entendido una interfaz no puede ser instanciada, no se si alguien pudiera aclárame esta duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto lo que planteas, tal como se indica en la [especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1). En la instanciación con cuerpo, si el tipo a instanciar (en el ejemplo, `ActionListener`) es una interfaz, entonces se declara una subclase anónima de `Object` que implementa dicha interfaz, y el tipo del objeto creado corresponderá con esta clase anónima declarada.

En otras palabras, el objeto creado, pertenece a una subclase de `java.lang.Object` que incluye la implementación de los métodos de la interfaz `ActionListener`. Al asignarse el objeto a la variable `fontas`, permite solamente acceder a los métodos de la interfaz, como indica el tipo de la variable.